# Can't create accounts in a java program

Tags: java, default-constructor

I have to write a program which creates 4 different accounts and outputs them using different constructors.
I have no idea how to use the default constructor to make an account for certain users, because there are no parameters in the constructor and the instructions did not have a method to take the name. (This is also not based on user input, but pre-set).

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: No anger, but we do expect that you can read the stackoverflow guidelines, so: edit your post. Look to the right. There's a "How to Format" section. Click the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link. Read it, apply that knowledge.

Comment: Hey Mike, thank you i will do that next time.

Comment: Well, if you can't change the code and provide one for yourself, there must be other methods (getters and setters) which facilitate it. `Account a = new Account(); a.setName(someName);...` may be the only way. If not the class is basically useless.